# Android Dictionary call from browser or pdf viewer

Tags: android, dictionary

I am coding a dictionary project. Program is simply translate enlish to arabic or arabic to english. When navigating in browser or reading a pdf or word file, you may want to look a word translation. For example  when you long click a text in browser apk like chrome, a popup menu open. The thing what i want to do is  add a link text like "translate in dictionay" to this popup menu. 
When click this link in popup menu, My program is automatically run and search this word and translate it.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unfortunately not possible, because that popup is defined in the Chrome app.